# How to determine focus loss from div group in jquery.

Tags: javascript, jquery

How to determine focus loss from div having class name edit_div, this should trigger some event after focus loss from this particular div using jquery. The html DOM is given here.

```
<div class="main_div_container">
  <div class="preview_div">
    <strong>Title one</strong>
    <p>Title description</p>
  </div>
  <div class='edit_div'>
    <div class="text_field_div">
      <input id="txtInput1" type="text" />
    </div>
    <div class="text_field_desc">`enter code here`
      <textarea id="txtArea" rows="10" cols="20"></textarea>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

I tried this way but its not working.

```
$("div.edit_div").focusout(function() {
  $(this).find('a.save_edit').trigger('click');
});
```

Comment: A div isn't really focusable, do you really mean when the inputs inside the div's are blurred ?

Comment: Inside inputs fields are filled out and when the user either clicks or focuses outside the div it should trigger some event.

Comment: Are you using `$(document).ready`?

Comment: yes i have written that. @scheisse_minelli

Comment: You have to explain this better, you probably want something to fire when the input looses focus, just not sure what the DIV or clicking outside it, has to do with it ?

Comment: @sansarp: Just making sure

Comment: @adeneo, focusout docs states: `The focusout event is sent to an element when it, or any element inside of it, loses focus.` So the event should really be fired when the inside input got blurred.

Comment: @LcSalazar - That's because jQuery provides a convenient `focusout` method that bubbles, using the more proper `blur` event does not bubble, and the input should really be targeted. A DIV is still not focusable.

Comment: Its more like this: you have two input fields with some user input values, wrapped inside one div. When you attempt to move out of that div group any event is required to fire out which clicks save button to submit form.

Answer (score 1):

```
$( "div .edit_div" ).focusout(function() {
   //something      })
```

[working copy](http://jsfiddle.net/je1fny6m/)